# Webview Loads some internal URLs and hence My "Please Wait" Loader fluctuates

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

I have one WebView in my android App which i use to log into my App.
The URL which I load in WebView is "https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin#identifier" with ru to my website.

Before loading I start a progress dialog which says "Please wait".

```
@Override
                public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
                    super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
                    Utils.mShowProgrossDiolog(mContext);
                }

                @Override
                public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String inComingURL) {
                    super.onPageFinished(view, inComingURL);
                    Utils.mHideProgrossDiolog();
                }
```

Problem is since WebView loads some internal URLs to verify and other things...My Loader fluctuates as show-hide-show-hide.

I want it to hide only when final site is loaded. Can someone help me what to do in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the loaded URL using `vwebView.getUrl();` in 
 `public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String inComingURL)` and only if it matches the URL you want to load dismiss the progress dialog. You might have to handle cases like when the url doesnt load at all.

Comment: In this case i know starting URL but since starting URL is of third party...i do not know ending URL...That is the problem in this case

Comment: No...URL being third party me load any number of pages and they may change later even if hardcode it to some number based on some number.

Comment: A long shot maybe to make the final website call some function in the your app through the javaScript interface, but I am not so sure about it.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the progress of page loading by web chrome client and once it reach to 100% you can hide your dialog.

```
private class MyWebChromeClient extends WebChromeClient{
    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int newProgress) {
        super.onProgressChanged(view, newProgress);
        if(newProgress==100){
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
}
```

You have to set webview client for your web view to get callback.

```
webView.setWebChromeClient(new MyWebChromeClient());
```

Comment: It  suffers from same problem...Progress becomes 100% for intermediate pages and hence progress bar hides and than for new intermediate page..it starts again...